# How do I avoid the SSL error using hipchat-api on Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ssl, rubygems, openssl, ruby-1.9.3

I am getting the below error when I am trying to send a message or perform any action.

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate
>   B: certificate verify failed

This error occurs only on ruby 1.9.3 p484. Works fine on 1.8.7.

I came across other similar issues(not specific to hipchat-api gem) and one of the solutions provided was to set the verify_mode to OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE. I tried it but isn't working for me or I am not sure if I am doing it right. Can anyone let me know what needs to be done..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just downgraded the httparty gem to a older version(0.11.0) and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your SSL certificates need to be updated.  If you're using RVM, you can use their tool to update.  Try

```
 rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

See http://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates for more details on updating using RVM.